# Is it possible to execute an onAction event when a custom ribbon tab is clicked

Tags: excel, vba, events, ribbonx

I have working .xlam application that contains a custom ribbon. This works great but the menu items under my tab sometimes disappear. I would like to add an onAction to the main tab for the add-in in the ribbon's CustomUI.xml but Excel must see this as a syntax error in the .xml and doesn't load the ribbon.

Is there a way to get an OnAction to fire when the ribbon's tab is clicked?

Comment: I think it would be useful to include the not-working XML you're using for this.

Comment: I've answered the stated question. As Mathieu writes in his comment, to solve the actual problem (tab content disappearing) it would certainly be necessary to see the Ribbon XML and related code ***in a new question***. If there's a lot of XML and code, please pare it down to a [mcve]... When doing so, you might well come across whatever is causing the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Office Fluent UI (Ribbon X) schema does not define/allow an `onAction` attribute for a `tab` control.

So, no, what is asked in the question is not allowed / not possible.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that. I have an InvalidateRibbon() sub. I would have liked to call it on the tab click but, as you said, this is not supported. Since the ribbon sometimes just disappears, I need to find an suitable event to call this sub to refresh (invalidate) the menu often. I was hoping that you (or others) might be able to suggest a suitable event to place this code in.